# How to solve this error message in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, installation, r-markdown

I am just starting to explore the `rmarkdown` package. I don't use `Rstudio`. I use the default R environment. What I did was as follows.

I created a new R document.
Started typing few lines in `rmarkdown` format.
Saved the file with `Rmd` extension.
I saved the file in the working directory.
I installed the `pandoc` using the pkg file.
I installed 'rmarkdown' package. Loaded the package. 
Used the following command to render the `Rmd` file.

```
rmarkdown::render("Untitled.Rmd")
```

I get the following error.

> Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(input) : file 'Untitled.Rmd'
>   does not exist

I tried all the possible ways such as giving the exact path instead of filename etc. But nothing worked out. I googled the error message and found that none had similar error. Can someone help me with this. What I am missing. What the error message mean?

Comment: Use `dir()` and make sure `"Untitled.Rmd"` is in your working directory.  If it's not use `setwd()` to make it so or provide the full file path to the document.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: Can you state what format you want the document to be in? I assume you want the RMarkdown file to output a HTML, PDF, or Microsoft Word document? Would the [knitr](http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell) package work?

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean exactly?  Does `list.files(pattern="Untitled.Rmd")` return anything other than a zero-length vector?

Comment: I suspect the file is misspelled (or different letter case) some how differently than what is being passed to `render`.

Comment: @TylerRinker I figured out just now. Though the file name appeared like Untitled.Rmd, When I found info about the file I found its Untitled.Rmd.R. Thats why I got the error. Even for other files I got same error and it should be because of this file extension issue. I made a mistake when i saved the file with Rmd extension. Now I got it solved.

Comment: I got the same error and no clue how to solve it

Comment: Try absolute file locations rather than relative to see if that helps. 
(.n.b. looks like a similar issue reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224162/knitr-wont-compile-pdf-error-in-toolsfile-path-as-absoluteoutput-file)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time the error `file not found` is either a type error or a real missing file (as in your case, the real one is named in another way).

In order to discard those possibilities:

1. Copy the fullpath from your filebrowser.
2. Make sure the file exists, inside R you could type:

   `file.exists("/fullpath/to/file")`

If that return TRUE and the error persists, then you suspect another thing is going on.