# Knitr wont compile PDF: "Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file)"

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I have created a report in markdown and use the function `render()` to compile the code into a PDF. It worked fine a month ago, but when I run the code now, it gives me an error:

> Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 22 April 2016, version: 4.45.
>   Output created: output/Medborgerskabstabeller99.pdf
>
> Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) : 
>   file 'output/Medborgerskabstabeller99.pdf' does not exist

The render command I use to create the PDF looks like this:

```
outfile <- file.path("output",paste0("Medborgerskabstabeller99"))
render(input = "Medborgerskabstabeller.Rmd",
       encoding = "UTF-8",
       output_file = paste0(outfile,".pdf"))
```

First of all, the "Latexmk"-message before did not appear when the code worked.

Second, I have no clue why it says that "Medborgerskabstabeller99.pdf" doesn't exist, when it says above that it just created the file.

Any suggestions on the problem will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The Latexmk message isn't a problem. Does your `output/` directory exist and are you able to open the pdf?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Phil! When I type `dir.exists("output")` R returns `TRUE`, so I guess my output/ directory does exists. In the mean time I discovered that `render()` does create a PDF-file, if I delete the `output_file=` argument. It solves my problem, but I still don't know what went wrong before.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 26):

A better solution appears to be to use tinytex.

```
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

If you have to use MikTex and have it installed already, open the MikTex console and change the missing package setting to:

```
Always install missing packages on the fly
```

If you have not installed MikTex yet then on installation make sure to choose:

```
Install missing packages: Yes
```

When I originally installed I chose `Ask me first` and it would fail. I have tried both changing the settings of MikTex, as well as uninstalled it and just settled for tinytex which was a bit more lightweight for my needs.

The original thread with solution near the bottom:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285

Comment: Allowing miktex to install the packages on fly helped. For a note, make sure that the proxy is set in `miktex package manager(admin)`, if internet is connected through internet

Comment: More direct link to what I think is meant as [near the bottom](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285#issuecomment-374340175).

Answer (score 16):

I had similar problem. After searching in the internet, I found a solution in [community r studio](https://community.rstudio.com/t/new-problems-producing-pdf-from-rmarkdown/5850)

It seems the bug is related with 1.9 version of rmarkdown, so the solution is to return to 1.8 version

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_version("rmarkdown",version=1.8)
```

After reinstalling, when you try to knit again, probably you will be asked to install some package from Miktex. If you have any problem, check for a proper mirror. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was having the same issue, and @Juan's solution seems to have solved it.

Comment: fyi, this solution still works, while version 1.10.2 doesn't.

Comment: Dude, I was having a ton of problems when making reports for my boss with the computer I have at work and this completely solved it. Good god, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: I was having the same issue, followed the directions you provided above, and installed an additional 10 TeX-related packages after rolling back to 'rmarkdown' v1.8.   It works marvelously now - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile the issue seems to be fixed in the development version `1.10.11`:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')
```

Comment: I tried this solution, and the package is upgraded to 1.10.2, however, it still doesn't work. while @jaySf's solution works by downgrading to 1.8.

Comment: @HappyCoding You're half right. I just had to do it again myself. At first it really didn't work with the current rmarkdown version 1.10.11. I then tried _juan-acosta_'s downgrade solution to version 1.8. During the start of the PDF compilation process MiKTeX fetched essential latex packages, which obviously the current version didn't manage. Then I updated back to the latest rmarkdown version (1.10.11) and it worked. There is an ongoing discussion on [Github](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1385) that could shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment to the output question, as I got stuck with this, too: 
the `outfile` must be the absolute path. I think `dir.exists()` looks in the local working directory. Using `".\\"` in front helped in my case. In yours it would be using `paste0(".\\",outfile,".pdf")`.

Answer (score 0):

If using MikTex, you probably missing some packages (basic Miktex packages are installed). Just compile your tex file to find out missing packages (compile errors) and install them. Then knit your rmd document and it should work.