# r markdown to pdf error on output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm getting an error when Knit to pdf in rstudio using R markdown. It works without issue to Knit to html.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Output created: PA1_template.pdf
Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) : 
  file 'PA1_template.pdf' does not exist
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode     "PA1_template.tex"' had status 1 
2: In readLines(logfile) :
  incomplete final line found on 'PA1_template.log'
Execution halted
```

Any help on how to fix the issue would be appreciated.

James

Comment: Can you reproduce the error? A reproducible example would help....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knitr wont compile PDF: "Error in tools::file\_path\_as\_absolute(output\_file)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224162/knitr-wont-compile-pdf-error-in-toolsfile-path-as-absoluteoutput-file)

Answer (score 5):

Resolved the above for me, please see below:

Hi all,

I finally got markdown knitting. Here’s a github link with the solution: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285#issuecomment-374340175

1. Make sure the Miktex console settings > General > install missing packages on the fly
2. Install the dev version of tinytex in r studio
   install.packages('rmarkdown')
   devtools::install_github('yihui/tinytex')
3. Also, I had changed this: In R-Studio Tools > Global Options, under the Sweave tab, try changing "Weave Rnw using:"

If I get nothing else done today, this will still make it a day to remember.