# Error when kniting markdown to PDF

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I know similar questions have been asked before but I still baffled as to why this does not work for me. I am trying to knit a .RMD document to PDF but keep seeing the following error:

Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) : file 'DRAFT_AMR_annual_report_final_2018.pdf' does not exist

The following code has been used to format the document for PDF:

> --- title: "Surveillance of Antimicrobial Use and Resistance in Northern   Ireland,  \nAnnual Report, 2018"
>   fontsize: 12pt
>   header-includes:
>   - \usepackage{setspace}
>   - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
>   - \usepackage{url}
>   - \usepackage{lmodern}
>   - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
>   - \usepackage{helvet}
>   - \usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}
>   output:
>     pdf_document:
>       fig_caption: yes
>       includes:
>         in_header: PHA_TEST2.tex
>   bibliography: bibliography.bib
>
> ### csl: bmj.csl

This exact document has been knitting to PDF successfully on my colleague's PC (along with other .RMD files) but not on mine. I am unable to understand why? Can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks mb21, I will check this out

Comment: It seems I can knit to Word and write into the relevant output folder but still not to PDF

Comment: Then `pdflatex` probably fails... but I cannot see anything related to that in the output you posted..

Comment: The full output message in the R Markdown screen after knitting says the following:

Comment: output file: DRAFT_AMR_annual_report_final_2018.knit.md

Comment: "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS DRAFT_AMR_annual_report_final_2018.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output DRAFT_AMR_annual_report_final_2018.tex --template "C:\Users\cnuge005\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\

Comment: default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --include-in-header PHA_TEST2.tex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --variable "compact-title:yes" --include-in-header "C:\Users\cnuge005\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO0UYt0\rmarkdown-str319840c14e02.html" --filter pandoc-citeproc

Comment: Output created: DRAFT_AMR_annual_report_final_2018.pdf
Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) : 
  file 'DRAFT_AMR_annual_report_final_2018.pdf' does not exist
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1] 
2: running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "DRAFT_AMR_annual_report_final_2018.tex"' had status 1 
3: In readLines(logfile) :
  incomplete final line found on 'DRAFT_AMR_annual_report_final_2018.log'
Execution halted

Comment: maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224162/knitr-wont-compile-pdf-error-in-toolsfile-path-as-absoluteoutput-file

Comment: Thanks again mb21!