# Consistent Error in LaTeX Output Error in R, execution halted

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown

After hours of searching and installing uninstalling R, MikTex etc. I give up.

I am trying to make tables based on our data analysis, use kableExtra to prettify them and then export and save them as pdf files. I have used both stable and dev versions for rmarkdown and tinytex. Also changing the latex engine in RStudio. Any help very appreciated.

```
Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.456)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2018-08-30                  

Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       source                            
 arsenal     * 1.3.0   2018-07-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 assertthat    0.2.0   2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 backports     1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                    
 base        * 3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 bindr         0.1.1   2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 bindrcpp      0.2.2   2018-03-29 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 colorspace    1.3-2   2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 compiler      3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 curl          3.2     2018-03-28 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 datasets    * 3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 devtools    * 1.13.6  2018-06-27 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 digest        0.6.16  2018-08-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 dplyr       * 0.7.6   2018-06-29 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 evaluate      0.11    2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 git2r         0.23.0  2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 glue          1.3.0   2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 graphics    * 3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 grDevices   * 3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 highr         0.7     2018-06-09 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 hms           0.4.2   2018-03-10 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 httr          1.3.1   2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 kableExtra  * 0.9.0   2018-05-21 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 knitr       * 1.20    2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 magick        1.9     2018-05-11 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 methods     * 3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 pillar        1.3.0   2018-07-14 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 pkgconfig     2.0.2   2018-08-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 purrr         0.2.5   2018-05-29 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 R6            2.2.2   2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 Rcpp          0.12.18 2018-07-23 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 readr         1.1.1   2017-05-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 rlang         0.2.2   2018-08-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 rmarkdown     1.10.12 2018-08-30 Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@6e56ad8)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 rsconnect     0.8.8   2018-03-09 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 rstudioapi    0.7     2017-09-07 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 rvest         0.3.2   2016-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 scales        1.0.0   2018-08-09 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 stats       * 3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 stringi       1.2.4   2018-07-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 stringr       1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 testthat      2.0.0   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 tibble        1.4.2   2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 tidyselect    0.2.4   2018-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 tools         3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 utils       * 3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 viridisLite   0.3.0   2018-02-01 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 xml2          1.2.0   2018-01-24 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                    
 yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```

my code is:

```
makePaperTable <- function(geneList, Results4wk,Results10wk,n,table_title){

  fourWeek <- Results4wk[,"genes"] %in% geneList
  tenWeek <- Results10wk[,"genes"] %in% geneList
  not_in <- geneList %in% Results4wk[,"genes"]
  cat(c("Number of Genes in Gene list provided:",length(geneList),"\n"))
  cat(c("Number of Genes in 4wk Results  : ",sum(fourWeek),"\n"))
  cat(c("Number of Genes in 10wk Results : ",sum(fourWeek),"\n"))
  cat(c("Genes:"), geneList[!not_in],"\n","\n" )

  table_joon <- merge(Results4wk[fourWeek,c("genes","FC","adj.P.Val")],Results10wk[tenWeek,c("genes","FC","adj.P.Val","Gene.description")], by="genes", all=T)

  colnames(table_joon) <- c("Gene Symbol", "Fold Change", "Adj. p-Value", "Fold Change", "Adj. p-Value",  "Gene Description")

table_joon$`Gene Description` <- tools::toTitleCase(gsub(x = table_joon$`Gene Description`, pattern  =  "\\[.*", replacement = "",perl = F) )

  table_joon[,2:5] <- sapply(table_joon[,2:5],prettyNum,digits=2)
  joon <- kable(table_joon, 
        caption = paste0("Table ", n,": ",stringr::str_replace_all(table_title,pattern = "\\.",replacement = " ")) ,
        format = "latex", 
        booktabs=T,
        align = c("l","c","c","c","c","l")) %>% 
    kable_styling(latex_options = "striped") %>%
    add_header_above(c(" ", " 4 Week Group" = 2, "10 Week Group" = 2),bold = T,align = "c")
  return(joon)
  }

Output created: tablesV2.pdf
Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) : 
  file 'tablesV2.pdf' does not exist
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(logfile) : incomplete final line found on 'tablesV2.log'
Execution halted
```

Comment: pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? There is no way that others could run your code as it seems to refer to some dataset. Do you get this problem when using the default at rmarkdown template?

Comment: If you haven't seen them, you might find info at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224162/knitr-wont-compile-pdf-error-in-toolsfile-path-as-absoluteoutput-file) and in the discussion at this [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285)