# How to jump to footnotes with activated 'setspace' and 'footmisc' package?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I just noticed that in clicking footnote links in the pdf makes the document jumps to the top instead to the footnote. Investigating why I identified the latex packages `setspace` and `footmisc` apparently causing the error.

Unfortunately I need both packages badly. The former to switch between `\onehalfspacing` and `\singlespacing` and the latter to get nice hanging footnotes.

Does anybody know a workaround?

***MWE***

(*Note:* Try un-commenting the outcommented lines. )

```
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "October 23, 2018"
output: pdf_document
linkcolor: blue
header-includes:
# - \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
- \usepackage{floatpag}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{icomma}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \usepackage{csquotes}
# - \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{mathtools,extarrows}
- \usepackage{changepage}
---

\newpage
Lorem ipsum^[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.] dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

---

***Notes:***

- MiKTeX 2.9.6850
- using outdated rmarkdown_1.8 intentionally ([*see this issue*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49708173/6574038))

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1  backports_1.1.2 rprojroot_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.5.1    
 [6] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_0.12.19    rmarkdown_1.8   knitr_1.20      digest_0.6.18  
[11] evaluate_0.12
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem (footnotes aren't links and thus not clickable anymore when using footmisc). Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to directly solve this in the `.Rmd` document itself. Instead I had to edit the Pandoc LaTeX template that's shipping with rmarkdown.

As @Mico explains in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169124/144087) on the TeX/LaTeX stack exchange site, the underlying problem is that the LaTeX package *hyperref* is called before *footmisc* while it has to be the other way round to avoid incompatibilities between the two. If you have a look into the default LaTeX template rmarkdown uses, you'll notice that hyperref is called way **before** the `header-includes` from the YAML front matter get injected. The only workaround for this I know of is to modify the LaTeX template, i.e. insert the line `\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}` before the line where hyperref is called.

In order to do this follow these steps:

1. Locate the original template file Pandoc uses when rmarkdown/knitr calls it.

   On Unix/Linux systems you'll find the original template file probably under the path `~/Library/R/3.5/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/` or `/usr/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/` (just replace the beginning of the path with what `.libPaths()` displays in your R console).

   At least in rmarkdown v1.10 the folder above contains 4 different LaTeX template files:

   - `default-1.14.tex`
   - `default-1.15.2.tex`
   - `default-1.17.0.2.tex`
   - `default.tex`

   `default-1.17.0.2.tex` seems the right choice if a halfway recent version of Pandoc is used (it's bundled with rmarkdown and will be used if no or only an antiquated Pandoc version can be found on your system; run `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` to find out what version is actually in use).

   <sub>First I tried `default.tex` but it turned out to be pretty outdated and `default-1.17.0.2.tex` works just fine.</sub>
2. Put that file's content into a fresh `template.tex` (or whatever you'd like to name it) file and insert your footmisc customization code before package hyperref is called (line 57).
3. Put the path to the new template file into the YAML front matter under the key `output.pdf_document.template`:

   ```
   ---
   output:
     pdf_document:
       template: 'path/to/template.tex'
   ---
   ```

BTW: I didn't experience any problem regarding package *setspace*. But I in my case it's loaded before *footmisc* anyway due to setting `linestretch` in the YAML front matter (see the template for details about what triggers setspace to get loaded etc.).

Comment: I'm sure to have followed all your steps, but it still jumps to the top. Using pandoc version `1.19.2.1`

Comment: hm, strange. I'm using the same Pandoc version `‘1.19.2.1’`. Are you sure it has nothing to do with the PDF viewery you're using?